Dataflow flex template deployment issue
I built an image using docker file and used requirements.txt file for installing certain module but however I get the below error while deploying flex template and I used python sdk.
ImportError: cannot import name 'secretmanager_v1' from 'google.cloud' (unknown location)
I tried by giving google-cloud-secret-manager==0.2.0 in requirements.txt file

hi Zam, couple of questions:

What's the python version?
Did you develop your template with 0.2.0 or earlier version?
Did you try with some up to date secret-manager lib version? Latest is 2.22.0 if I'm not wrong.
For more info on the build of the flex template check https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/using-flex-templates#build-template, in case you're missing some argument for the build.
Ps: I've tried on a pyenv virtualenv to import secretmanager_v1 with version 2.22.0, and it seems to work.

